# Async function always return undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

im using nodejs 8. I've replaced promise structure code to use async and await.

I have an issue when I need to return an object but await sentence resolve undefined.

This is my controller method:

```
request.create = async (id, params) => {
    try {
        let request = await new Request(Object.assign(params, { property : id })).save()
        if ('_id' in request) {
            Property.findById(id).then( async (property) => {
                property.requests.push(request._id)
                await property.save()

                let response = {
                    status: 200,
                    message: lang.__('general.success.created','Request')
                }

                return Promise.resolve(response)
            })
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        let response = {
            status: 400,
            message: lang.__('general.error.fatalError')
        }

        return Promise.reject(response)
    }               
}
```

In http request function:

```
exports.create = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let response = await Request.create(req.params.id, req.body)
        console.log(response)
        res.send(response)
    }

    catch (err) {
        res.status(err.status).send(err)
    }
}
```

I tried returning `Promise.resolve(response)` and `Promise.reject(response)` with `then` and `catch` in the middleware function and is occurring the same.

What's wrong?

Thanks a lot, cheers

Comment: You're not `await`ing the `Property.findById(id).then(…)` promise. In fact you probably should use `then` at all here, but just `const property = await Property.findById(id); …`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to interact with the promises at all inside an `async` function. Inside an `async` function, the regular `throw` syntax is the same as `return Promise.reject()` because an `async` function *always* returns a `Promise`. Another thing I noticed with your code is that you're rejecting promises inside a HTTP handler, which will definitely lead to unexpected behavior later on. You should instead handle all errors directly in the handler and act on them accordingly, instead of returning/throwing them.

Your code could be rewritten like so:

```
request.create = async (id, params) => {
  let request = await new Request(Object.assign(params, { property : id })).save()
  if ('_id' in request) {
    let property = await Property.findById(id)
    property.requests.push(request._id)
    await property.save()
  }
}
```

And your http handler:

```
exports.create = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await Request.create(req.params.id, req.body)
    res.send({
      status: 200,
      message: lang.__('general.success.created','Request')
    })
  } catch (err) {
    switch (err.constructor) {
      case DatabaseConnectionError: // Not connected to database
        return res.sendStatus(500) // Internal server error
      case UnauthorizedError:
        return res.sendStatus(401) // Unauthorized
      case default:
        return res.status(400).send(err) // Generic error
    }
  }
}
```

Error classes:

```
class DatabaseConnectionError extends Error {}
class UnauthorizedError extends Error {}
```

Because you have that `try/catch` block inside your http handler method, anything that `throw`s or `reject`s inside the `Request.create` method will be caught there. See https://repl.it/LtLo/3 for a more concise example of how errors thrown from `async` function or `Promise`s doesn't need to be caught directly where they are first called from.

Comment: Works fine, shortest, excellent. I've confused about `try/catch`. Thank you very much.

Comment: When await Property.findById(id) fails, must i to use `try`and `catch` to throw the error?

Comment: No, this will be caught by your `try/catch` block inside the `exports.create` function. *Any function* that `throw`s or `return Promise.reject()` that gets called throughout the function call chain of the `Request.create` method *will be caught* by the `try/catch` block inside `exports.create`. To make it crystal clear, *you only need that `try/catch` block*.

Comment: I understood that now. But, how to return in controller method a different object if error occurs with find sentence?

Comment: Oh I missed that part of your code. Generally, you want your http handler to handle what type of response to respond with, and the response should thus be moved to the `exports.create` function. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, but some controllers will be used in some internal scripts and they will not requested throug `http`. Http handlers just get data and send controller results.

Comment: It's hard to come up with a good example, but you don't want to pass around JS Objects simply telling other functions that it was successful. If the function `throw`s/`reject`s it failed, if it doesn't, it was successful. You can use a `switch` statement to match what type of error was thrown, and act accordingly.

Comment: Your answer updated seems to be the best way, when I call a controller's method that returns a http response and just data is taken. thank you so much. I'm refactoring all code.

Comment: @uruapanmexicansong I'm glad I could be of help! I updated my answer to show how you'd handle errors. These are thrown with `throw new UnauthorizedError("Unauthorized")` or `return Promise.reject(new UnauthorizedError("Unauthorized"))`.

Comment: Wow, I came looking for copper and found gold.

Comment: This could be helpful to someone... If promise throws a mongoose error: `Object.keys(err.constructor.messages)[0] || err.constructor`